# reset_value does not reset the value on reaching upper limit on get_next_value

Tags: python, django

The steps are as follows:

```
from sequences import get_next_value, get_last_value 

get_next_value('nu', initial_value=0, reset_value=1000) 

l = [get_next_value('nu') for i in range(1001)]
```

Can one help what is wrong here? The requirement is to generate a sequence of numbers and set the counter to the initial value after it reaches an upper limit.  The library used is django-sequences

Answer (score 0):

This reason is that the user should be done in a proper way as given below:

```
with transaction.atomic(): 
    print([get_next_value('n1', initial_value=1, reset_value=100) for i in range(100)])
```